# How to configure Role Management in azure Static web app

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

I am trying to set up authentication in my azure static web app through google. I am able to configure a custom tole management and that is assigning a role to the user.

But those users who log in don't show up in the role management tab of the static web app. How can I make sure the user who loges in shows in there with the correct role assigned to them.

Answer (score 0):

Only invited users will show up in the role management tab of the static web app. Make sure you invite the users first